# When iterating through a FileSystemInfo[] my C# application crashes without an exception

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

I have an application that polls a directory for newly-added files and processes any new ones. It's a C# (.NET 4) app running on Windows 7, and the directory is in fact a network share.

The problem is, while iterating thorugh the files to check that they exist, the app sometimes crashes without throwing an exception. (I do use try-catch, and there's no unmanaged code, or delegate code, or anything abnormal. It's a simple app)

The iterating code looks like this:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dp = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(destinationPath);
System.IO.FileSystemInfo[] destinationFiles = dp.GetFileSystemInfos();

foreach (FileSystemInfo fileSysInfo in destinationFiles)
{
  string filePath = fileSysInfo.FullName;
  if (filePath.EndsWith(FILE_VALID_EXT) && !Directory.Exists(filePath) && !File.Exists(filePath + FILE_PROCESSED_EXT))
  {
    // Do processing. It doesn't reach this point! I know because I have a logging statement.
  }
}
```

Is the code failing because the remote directory is (temporarily) unavailable? Or because there's some sort of lock on a file or the directory?

How can I avoid this? Maybe there's a safer way to use the C# File I/O API.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: it could be bcos of lock, like may be another process is accessing the file, or may be you do not have enough privileges etc

Comment: How did you wrap your try..catch? Maybe it was failing outside the try..catch when initializing your objects.

Comment: Do not use Directory.Exist to check if the FileSystemInfo is a directory or file. Use FileSystemInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory.

Comment: @nawfal: I do have enough privilege because this works most of the time. I agree it might be lock-related, but if so how can I avoid it? Also, I would expect an exception if there were locking but I don't get that...

Comment: @ericosg: Yes, that was the first thing I was thinking about but the try/catch definitely wraps around all of that code, including the initialisation part. In addition I have a lot of logging statements so I know that the initialisation worked for sure...

Comment: @Steve: I will try that. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Without knowing what you do in the processing loop is difficult to say. The only critical point in that code is Directory.Exist or File.Exist that could trigger an exception. Perhaps the problem is originated in your processing loop.

Comment: Please show us the try catch. And tell us which line is the exception hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when a .net application crashes without notice is because of a stack overflow. Just an idea: Check if the directory structure you are enumerating has a symbolic link causing an infinite loop.